# Bamboo indices in ArcMap

Tags: arcmap, vegetation-index

I have been working from a long time for bamboo area assessment using ArcMap. I used Bamboo (BI) to assess potential bamboo area of my study site. I used last 5 year’s Landsat-8 and Sentinel-2 data for it. I first calculated NDVI and then Soil Moisture Index (SMI) for it as BI is calculated as BI = (NDVI-SMI)/(NDVI+SMI) with datatype as float.
NDVI was calculated as: NDVI= (Band5-Band4)/(Band5+Band4) for Landsat-8 & NDVI= (Band8-Band4)/(Band8+Band4) for Sentinel-2.

The formula for SMI is calculated as: SMI=(NIR-SWIR)/(NIR+SWIR).
Likewise, SMI was calculated as: SMI= (Band5-Band6)/(Band5+Band6) for Landsat-8 & SMI=(Band8-Band12)/(Band8+Band12) for Sentinel-2.

Similarly, I calculated BI for both Landsat-8 and Sentinel-2. The output should have BI value between 0 and 1. However, BI pixel value wasn’t obtained as between 0 and 1 (for instance as shown for BI_Sentinel2019).

[image]

Why is this occurring and be solved???